# Generate uniform floating point numbers with accurate distribution

Tags: python

I found this [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) on the python docs to generate uniformly distributed random floats in the range 0.0 <= f < 1.0. I am trying to write my own version of the function without power/log functions to speed up generation of random numbers.

In my version, all floats with precision of 2^-84 are possible selections. The mantissa comes from a uniform distribution of integers in the range [0, 2^52). The exponent is generated from an exponential distribution of integer powers of two in the range [2^-53, 2^-84], where the exponent is -53 with probability 1/2, -54 with probability 1/4, -55 with probability 1/8, and so on.

Any more suggestions for further optimizations or to improve the distribution of the function output?

Edit:

The main goal is to generate floats as uniform as possible, without any bias in the lower bits.

```
from sys import float_info
import random

def fRandom():
    mantissa = random.getrandbits(52)
    significand = 1.0 + mantissa * float_info.epsilon
    x = 0
    while not x:
        x = random.getrandbits(32)
        x = x & -x  # bitmask for rightmost 1-bit (exponential)
        #print("x=",x)
    return significand / (2 * x)
```

Comment: I'd suggest getting rid of the `  >> 12 ` part. If you leave it in, you won't get any mantissa larger than 2^40, meaning that the largest number it can create is `0.500122` or so.

Comment: It was a mistake from an old version i copied from.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the distribution of the output values, the output seems reasonably well-distributed.

However, timing-wise, I found it to be slower than the core implementation:

```
%timeit fRandom()
418 ns ± 2.99 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit random.random()
62.2 ns ± 1.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

It's also going to be hard to make it faster than the core implementation, as that's written in C, and has only two lines:

```c
static PyObject *
_random_Random_random_impl(RandomObject *self)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=117ff99ee53d755c input=afb2a59cbbb00349]*/
{
    uint32_t a=genrand_uint32(self)>>5, b=genrand_uint32(self)>>6;
    return PyFloat_FromDouble((a*67108864.0+b)*(1.0/9007199254740992.0));
}
```

The internal implementation does not use power/log. It uses only shift, addition, and multiply, which are fast.

Comment: division of randbits_53 / 2**53 (9007199254740992.0) has some bias in the lower bits. Check the lower 3 bits. They are non-uniform, with more 0's than 1's due to rounding to even. This a problem in all algorithms dividing by a fixed exponent,

Comment: I found this article that explains that bias more clearly. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7302591/

Comment: This is not a rounding problem, exactly. You can see this by looking at only those random numbers smaller than 1/256. All of these numbers have the bottom eight bits unset. That's not because of rounding - small numbers are actually easier to compute accurately. It's because in order to generate a number smaller than 1/256, the top eight bits of randbits_53 must be zero. Then the bits are shifted left to normalize the mantissa, leaving the bottom eight as zero. This bias means that the probability of each mantissa bit being zero is slightly higher than 1/2.

Comment: Anyhow, if the goal is a more accurate distribution of random numbers, then I'd suggest adding that into the question - I thought you were looking for something faster than the version in the core library.

Comment: Yes, it was not clear in the question. Thanks for the benchmark.

Comment: the problem is mostly due to rounding because you try to fit 2^53 pigeons into 2^52 holes, so some holes contains more than 1 pigeon, resulting in rounding. if you generate just enough 2^52 pigeons, no rounding will occur. This can be demonstrated in python core function if it was implemented like that: PyFloat_FromDouble((((uint64_t)(a*67108864.0+b))  | 1)*(1.0/9007199254740992.0));